# How to automatically resize a font for a given height and width when creating an image (e.g. .jpeg)

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, fonts, drawing

I'm writing a C# WPF application which creates pictures (.jpeg files).

What I want to do is draw text on the picture inside a given area using the graphics library. Since I don't know how long the text will be I want to resize the font in such a way, that the text will be shown without leaving too much space of the given area empty and without being cut for long texts - it should just lower the font size until the text fits inside.

Currently I'm using a `System.Drawing.RectangleF` to define the space for the text because it allows me to wrap the text automatically when I insert it using `Graphics.DrawString`.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a useful way to resize the text accurately and so I wrote a method that counts the characters of the string and lowers the size depending on how many characters I thought might being cut off. It's a very ugly approach that took a lot of tinkering and re-checking of the output image without ever being actually accurate.

Is there a better way to measure and adjust the size of my text in C#?

Or maybe it doesn't even have to be measured and there's something like the XAML `ViewBox` around for drawing graphics that I just don't know of yet?

Comment: This is not a "Possible Duplicate" because I´m drawing on a Image and not on the screen therefore I cannot use a Viewbox - or at least I think so. Please read my question before editing it!

Comment: Hi Samuel, I'm rolling back your edit to re-insert the duplicate link so users can see which question this was marked as a duplicate to, but can you edit your question a bit to clarify how it's different from the linked question, and explain why a `ViewBox` won't work? It will help get your question reopened (which will automatically remove the duplicate link), and help users provide you with a better answer. (It would also be helpful to see the code you've got already). I've already voted to reopen, but it needs 4 other user votes to get reopened.

Comment: Hi Rachel. Thanks for the help! Since I mentioned the fact that I´m dealing with pictures in my first sentence and the Viewbox is a xaml control for UIs it´s probably useless to edit the text when nobody (except you ;) reads it. But I´ll try the title.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I didn't immediately realize you were asking about drawing fonts on an image using the graphics library, and not XAML.

Comment: Some code may help. This also may be of some use http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/dd98e50a-cc00-4252-bd03-c9b51bf3634d